# OpenGL display textures correctly

Tags: opengl, textures, render-to-texture

I'm rendering textures on the two surfaces which actually have the same location and position.

In these kind of cases I want to display only one of the textures, while I get following

[image]

I.e. I want only the texture of first material to be displayed.

So I would like to know where I've to search for solution, should I play with the blending of the materials ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty old issue ([z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)) as the card isn't sure which object to draw in front. The linked Wikipedia article has more examples of this.

To fix this, increase the depth buffer's accuracy (bit depth), reduce the depth of your view (distance far/near clip plane) or add a tiny offset so the coordinates are no longer exactly (or almost) the same. You could as well simply disable the depth buffer (or clear it) for rendering this (in which case whatever is rendered last will overlap everything else).

Comment: Maybe use glPolygonOffset() for offsetting one of the polygons?

Comment: Anything moving the vertices would work, however the required distance might be different depending on your hardware and drivers. There's no 100% foolproof way as long as you keep the Depth Buffer active.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to display few textures at one time? Use multi texturing then. Attach both textures to one Quad using:

```
glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE1_ARB, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

And play with `glTexEnvi` to combine them as you want. If you want to show only one of your textures then draw two quads with separate textures on each of them. And quad witch will be drawn later will be visible. Then if you want to turn from one to another, make separate `-(void)`'s for each of quad, with `glClearColor` before each quad drawing and then make button to call for example `-(void)quad1` and button to call `-(void)quad2`.

Or just use depth buffer.

At your situation i would use multi texturing, because all buffers looked too hard for me all time.

---

I will show how would my code look like.

Code using multi texture:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//Turn on blending and set glBlendFunc for your needs
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

//Describing multitexturing
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB); //Activating texture on unit 0
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB); //Activating texture on unit 0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture1); //Bind texture on unit 0
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //Enable GL_TEXTURE_2D to set it's glTexEnvi for your needs
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE ); //Edit glTexEnvi for your needs (link bellow code)
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GL_INTERPOLATE );

glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1_ARB); //Activating texture on unit 1
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1_ARB); //Activating texture on unit 1
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture2); //Bind texture on unit 0
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //Enable GL_TEXTURE_2D to set it's glTexEnvi for your needs
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE ); //Edit glTexEnvi for your needs (link bellow code)
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GL_REPLACE );

//Drawing quad with multi texture
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB, 0.0f, 0.0f); //Texture on unit 0 coords
glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE1_ARB, 0.0f, 0.0f); //Texture on unit 1 coords 
glVertex2f(0.0, 500);
glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB, 0.0f, 1.0f); //Texture on unit 0 coords
glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE1_ARB, 0.0f, 1.0f); //Texture on unit 1 coords 
glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB, 1.0f, 1.0f); //Texture on unit 0 coords
glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE1_ARB, 1.0f, 1.0f); //Texture on unit 1 coords  
glVertex2f(800, 0.0);
glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB, 1.0f, 0.0f); //Texture on unit 0 coords
glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE1_ARB, 1.0f, 0.0f); //Texture on unit 1 coords 
glVertex2f(800, 500);
glEnd();

//Disable GL_TEXTURE_2D. We don't need it anymore
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//Disable blending
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
//Flush everything
glFlush();
```

Code for using one quad for each texture

```
-(void) drawQuad1 
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture1);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0, 500);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(800, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(800, 500);
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glFlush();
}

-(void) drawQuad2
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture2);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0, 500);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(800, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(800, 500);
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glFlush();
}

//and now when you want to draw `drawQuad1` you need to do `[self drawQuad1];`
//and where you want to draw `drawQuad2` you need to do `[self drawQuad2];`
```

Info about glTexEnvi [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml). Its just sample code. Fast written so could have mistakes. Sorry if i forgot something. Just i haven't been doing it for long time. Written it on Mac OS X, so if you are using other platform maby you will have to change few things (not opengl). And about depth buffer? I don't know how to use it. So I can't explain it for you. Sorry. Never used them.

Comment: Downvoting for trying to help. Thats nice :)

Comment: Tough crowd here. ;) Perhaps you can edit your answer? Statements like "make separate -(void)'s for each of quad" is vague. "Or just use depth buffer" is also not helpful - OP is already using it.

Comment: Thanks. Actually blending is not required here. Also, depth buffer being very important in OpenGL, it might be a good idea to read up on it. Regards.